# call to event listeners of a certain element instead of the one in the event listeners of the body

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have a eventListeners for all the body for touchevents but inside a certain element that is inside the body I want to make different thing for those touchevents. The problem is that even if I add eventListeners to that element when I touch the element it calls to the eventListener that is set for the body.
How can I make to remove the body eventListener but only in the element that I want? or to call to the eventListener that I put in the element instead of call to the eventListener that is in the body?

Comment: What have you tried, post some code? Anyway, `if (e.target.something == 'something') alert('this is not the elements you are looking for');`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use event.stopPropagation().

Here you can read more about it:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp

Comment: This is not working... I put a little example that is not working here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413572/touch-events-not-working it seems that the addeventListeners that I put are not working properly :(